# What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two *tank*plank builds for top lane or jungle?

Tags: league-of-legends

I go Philosopher's Stone>Wriggle's Lantern>Mercury's Treads>Spirit Visage>Frozen Heart>Thornmail.

Sometimes I get Ionian Boots of Lucidity. That gives me a ton of sustain and cooldown reduction to spam Gangplank's ult.

The other way I see tank-plank built is Warmog's Armor + Atma's Impaler.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each build?

Comment: Side note, waiting so long to get boots will make surviving in top lane near impossible and effectively ganking as jungle a real pain.

Comment: I'm assuming the build isn't purchased in that exact order.  It's definitely good to get lvl 1 boots and a vamp scepter early.

Comment: Toast, you are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at each item, and how it affects [Gangplank](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gangplank_the_Saltwater_Scourge):

- [Philosopher's Stone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher's_Stone) - this is a strong item on many champions.  It gives him the mana regen he needs to use Parrrley, HP regen, and GP/5.
- [Wriggle's Lantern](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wriggle's_Lantern) - provides armor, AD, life steal, a unique passive and a free ward.  This is another strong pick, especially if jungling Gangplank.
- [Mercury Treads](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mercury's_Treads) - these boots are considered the default tank boots, due to MR and tenacity.
- [Spirit Visage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Visage) - provides health, magic resist, CDR, and a boost to healing.  I don't recommend this item because it doesn't synergize well with any of his abilities.
- [Frozen Heart](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frozen_Heart) - provides armor, mana, CDR, and an aura debuff.  This item is best vs an auto-attack heavy team, otherwise I would skip it.
- [Thornmail](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thornmail) - provides armor, and deals magic damage when auto-attacked.  I don't recommend this item on Gangplank, because a clever opponent will stop focusing Gangplank when they see you've purchased it.  Since your goal is to be a tank, this is counter-productive.
- [Warmogs Armor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warmog's_Armor) - provides the most health in any item, and good health regen.  Helpful for staying alive.
- [Atma's Impaler](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Atma's_Impaler) - provides 15 AD for every 1k HP, armor, and crit chance.  A solid pick if you have extra health from runes/items.

The first build you've listed is very defensive.  You end with 229 armor and 55 MR.  This build would be most effective against a team that relies on auto-attacks (Master Yi, Ashe, etc).  It's going to be weaker vs a team doing primarily magic damage.  Warmog's and Atma's provides more health (good if you have armor/MR), and some damage, which helps

If you're jungling Gangplank, it's common to rush a Wriggle's first.  If you're top lane, 
you're going to focus on spamming Parrrley instead, so I'd recommend rushing a Philosopher's stone.  [Sheen](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sheen) is a common pick, because Parrrley trigger's Sheen's bonus damage.  It also builds into a [Triforce](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity_Force), an item that boosts all of Gangplank's abilities.

Every game is different, and you have to build vs your enemy team.  Of all the items listed, Mercury Treads and a Philosopher's stone are always viable.  Wriggle's is very common to see on him, and most of the time will be a good pick.  From there, build a sheen if you're using Parrrley a lot, or health, armor, and/or magic resist depending on what's doing the most damage to you.

**tl;dr**: Mercury Treads, Philosopher's Stone, and Wriggle's Lantern are almost always good picks.  Everything else is situational.

Comment: Awesome answer. I'd +2 if i could.

Answer (score 1):

First your build has no damage.

I would go fratma's (Frozen Mallet + Atma's Impaler) or atmogs (Atma's Impaler + Warmog's Armor) with any GP build I'm rolling as a bruiser.

Also, Thornmail is conditional.

- If the other team is focusing you with heavy attack damage.
- if they have a lot of life-steal (>30%).
- But if they have a lot of magic resistance, you probably shouldn't get it.

Comment: If one were to build fratmogs, which order would they be built?

Comment: I asked here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64760/in-what-order-should-i-build-frozen-mallot-atmas-impaler-and-warmogs-armor-top