# What order should I build Frozen Mallet, Atma's Impaler, and Warmog's Armor?

Tags: league-of-legends

I see the term "Fratmogs" thrown around in League of Legends.

What order should these items be built for top lane champions that would utilize them?

My opinion:

1. If you are agressive > [Atma's Impaler](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Atma%27s_Impaler)
2. If you are being pressed > [Warmog's Armor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warmog%27s_Armor)
3. If you are going for combo jungle ganks > [Frozen Mallet](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frozen_Mallet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term Fratmogs actually means to build all three items (Atmas, Warmogs, Frozen Mallet).

Fratmas, by contrast, means to build Frozen Mallet and Atmas

and Atmogs, means to build Warmog's and Atmas.

The order of the build depends on the game.

However, usually, if I'm building a bruiser, I will build a health item first (Warmog's or Frozen), and then follow that up with Atma's, and then finish of the trio with whichever health is remaining.

What health item I pick depends on a number of factors, but it kind of boils down to one of 2 things:

1. Do I need a lot more health and regen (Warmog's)
2. Do I need more CC (Frozen Mallet)

Comment: So you tend to build Atma's second always?

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you're top lane vs an opponent who does heavy AD damage, it might be better to buy a `Chain Vest` first, then a phage, then a phage, etc.  Or, if you're focusing on `Parrrley`, an early `Cloak of Agility` might be best.

Comment: @ericf I'll usually build some health before I build atma's, but as far as if it's a full warmog's or frozen, that depends. Getting a giant's belt or a phage, could be good enough depending.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that building the Atma's first is pointless as the item will not give you very much damage unless you build one of the health items first.  In regard to which of the health items to build first, it is all about incentive.  building warmog first allows you to get the passive stacked up early and provide you with massive amounts of health.  Of course the downside of this is that you will not be able to deal significant damage with just a warmog.  Building the frozen mallet first allows you to be aggresive as it gives you some damage and the slow on-hit, but this will leave you with less survivability than the warmog.  So depending on the lane this choice will vary.  If given a lead early, or if playing against a relatively squishy champ,  go for the frozen mallet so that you can remain aggressive and keep your opponent from being able to last hit well.  If playing against a very aggressive champ, or you fall behind in lane early, go for the warmog first as this will allow you to focus on getting cs to catch up in lane and stay alive.

Comment: Some formatting may improve readability of your answer